# Как конвертировать .ui в .py?

Tags: python, pyside2, pyside

Я хочу конвертировать ui файл в py файл
Я использую pyside2 и python 3.7
Я знаю что в pyside есть pysideuic

```
from pysideuic import compileUi
pyfile = open("C:\1f.py", 'w')
compileUi("C:\Login.ui", pyfile, False, 4,
False)
pyfile.close()
```

а что в pyside2? Просто постоянно использовать

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\Scripts\pyside2-uic.exe -g python -o С:\test1.py C:\test.ui
```

Очень неудобно

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете автоматизировать этот процесс. Например, добавляя ui-файлы в массив и затем генерируя py-файлы

```
    from os import path

    def ui2py():
        uis = ['file_1.ui', 'file_2.ui']
        for _ui in uis:
            output, ext = path.splitext(_ui)
            system('pyside2-uic {} > {}'.format(_ui, 'ui_' + output + '.py'))
```

функцию можно вызвать в файле main.py в самом начале

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8

def ui2py():
    ...

ui2py()

import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication
from Gui.MainWindow import MainWindow

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: А что мне нужно подключить что бы `ui2py()` конвертировал файлы? мне пишет что `NameError: name 'path' is not defined`

Comment: @sortfact добавил from .. import

Comment: теперь нету system

Answer (score 0):

Класс `QUiLoader` позволяет автономным приложениям динамически создавать пользовательские интерфейсы
во время выполнения, используя информацию, хранящуюся в файлах пользовательского интерфейса
или указанные в путях подключаемых модулей.
Больше https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html

```
import os
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtUiTools

class TestWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        file = QtCore.QFile(os.path.abspath("ui/mainwindow.ui"))
        file.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.window = loader.load(file, parent)
        file.close()
        self.window.show()

...
```

Comment: @sortfact что не так ?